# calculus 3, sequences and series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is there much use of sequences and series in calc 3? I had some issues with them in calc 2 and what to figure out if I should put a lot of time trying to get better before going into calc 3 or focus on other areas.

Comment: As far as I know, sequences and series are not needed in Calc 3 or an introductory course of Differential equations. They are however useful in further Differential equations where exact solutions cannot be obtained, and are "modelled" by series. It is however important for those courses to keep your integration techniques up to date...

Comment: Not needed... That is the best sentence I have heard all month... Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: If you intend to do a more or less usual curriculum of basic mathematics, you shall be doing some complex analysis, and there you're going to really need big time series in general

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close re: this question being primarily opinion based.  How is it subjective whether or not Calc 3 requires knowledge of sequences and series?  I get that Calc 3 curricula can differ from one place to another but that still doesn't make it a matter of opinion.  For example, it is a **fact** that when I took Calc 3, we needed to know nothing about sequences and series.  People who were in the same course as me are of course free to disagree.  And they wouldn't be of a different opinion, they would just be incorrect.

Comment: You really should try to get a handle on sequences and series before moving on because they're so basic.  However, usually Calc III involves higher dimensional integration and differentiation that usually doesn't involve too much series stuff directly but it's there certainly under the hood.  I think it's a bad idea to move on without understanding Calc II better than it seems you have.

Comment: In what order topics are covered in second-year calculus varies from one institution to another, and to some extent within institutions.   (By contrast, it was not so long ago considered very bold to write a first-year calculus textbook in which the mean value theorem was in section 4.2 rather than section 4.1.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequences and series are usually (and I say that loosely) taught in Calculus II. Some schools may not have time to cover this material (yet the AP exam still covers it). A math student (even engineering students too) don't really see these until differential equations when dealing with power series solutions or in their advanced calculus course.

Calculus III is where we extend our knowledge of calculus on the real line. What happens if I want to see how a function of two variables is changing? Can I integrate different kinds of functions? What other sorts of derivatives are there? These are the questions we provide answers to in Calculus III.